# Creating an Imbalanced Dataset

Tags: unbalanced-classes, synthetic-data

I would like to have my trained model tested on an imbalanced dataset. Is there any algorithms available to generate synthetic data from a balanced labelled dataset (spam/non-spam)?

Comment: You can always unbalance any data set by simply undersampling one class.

Answer (score 8):

Try [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html?highlight=smote), its an algorithm used for over-sampling. It creates *synthetic* samples from the class you want over-sampled.

You can use this to create any number of samples you need.

Comment: can SMOTE be used for under-sampling as well?

Comment: Well, you can obtain undersampling of class A by oversampling class notA ...

Comment: @StuartPeterson No, SMOTE is an over-sampling algorithm, but there are [many other](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-imblearn.under_sampling) under-sampling algorithms